# Eslint, how to accept const and arrow function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, eslint

This is probably somewhere around, but I simply can not find the answer.

Below is my eslint config file, but it doesn't accept const and arrow functions. How to change these settings to accept those? An alternative to eslint is welcome too.

```
{
    "ecmaFeatures": {
        "jsx": true,
        "arrowFunctions": true,
        "blockBindings": true,
        "defaultParams": true,
        "destructuring": true,
        "forOf": true,
        "generators": true,
        "objectLiteralComputedProperties": true,
        "objectLiteralShorthandMethods": true,
        "objectLiteralShorthandProperties": true,
        "restParams": true,
        "spread": true,
        "templateStrings": true,
        "modules": true,
        "classes": true
    },
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "jasmine": true,
        "node": true
    },
    "rules": {
        "brace-style": 2,
        "camelcase": 2,
        "comma-dangle": [2, "never"],
        "comma-spacing": [2, {
            "before": false,
            "after": true
        }],
        "comma-style": [2, "last"],
        "complexity": [1, 8],
        "consistent-this": [2, "_this"],
        "curly": 2,
        "default-case": 2,
        "dot-notation": 2,
        "eol-last": 2,
        "eqeqeq": 2,
        "guard-for-in": 1,
        "indent": [2, 2, {
            "SwitchCase": 1
        }],
        "key-spacing": [2, {
            "beforeColon": false,
            "afterColon": true
        }],
        "new-cap": 2,
        "new-parens": 2,
        "no-caller": 2,
        "no-debugger": 1,
        "no-dupe-args": 2,
        "no-dupe-keys": 2,
        "no-duplicate-case": 2,
        "no-eq-null": 0,
        "no-eval": 2,
        "no-implied-eval": 2,
        "no-invalid-regexp": 2,
        "no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs": 2,
        "no-redeclare": 2,
        "quote-props": [2, "consistent-as-needed"],
        "no-self-compare": 1,
        "no-shadow-restricted-names": 2,
        "no-trailing-spaces": 2,
        "no-undef": 2,
        "no-undef-init": 2,
        "no-underscore-dangle": 0,
        "no-unreachable": 2,
        "no-unused-vars": 1,
        "no-use-before-define": 2,
        "no-with": 2,
        "one-var": [2, "never"],
        "operator-assignment": [2, "always"],
        "quotes": [2, "single"],
        "radix": 2,
        "semi": [2, "always"],
        "semi-spacing": [2, {
            "before": false,
            "after": true
        }],
        "sort-vars": [1, {
            "ignoreCase": true
        }],
        "space-after-keywords": [2, "always"],
        "space-before-function-paren": [2, {
            "anonymous": "always",
            "named": "never"
        }],
        "space-in-parens": [2, "never"],
        "space-infix-ops": 2,
        "space-unary-ops": [2, {
            "words": true,
            "nonwords": false
        }],
        "strict": [2, "global"],
        "use-isnan": 2,
        "valid-jsdoc": 1,
        "yoda": [2, "never", {
            "exceptRange": false
        }]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From eslint docs:

> To address: If you are using any ECMAScript 6 feature flags in
>   ecmaFeatures, you’ll need to use ecmaVersion: 6 instead. The
>   ECMAScript 6 feature flags are:
>
> arrowFunctions - enable arrow functions
>
> binaryLiterals - enable binary literals
>
> blockBindings - enable let and const (aka block bindings)

```
// In your .eslintrc
{
    env: {
        es6: true
    }
}

// Or in a configuration comment
/*eslint-env es6*/
```

[`esLint`](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/migrating-to-2.0.0#language-options) there are a lot of examples

Hope it will help you